# AngularJS/Spring MVC - Trouble accessing form data in controller

Tags: java, json, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form where a user can have multiple addresses. An address contains for example of a street and country to keep things simple.

What I have is the following in my view. Whenever a user presses the button, a different div with input pops up, which works good.

```
<div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
    <input type="text" ng-model="address.streetname" placeholder="streetname"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="address.country" placeholder="country"/>
</div>
<button class="button" ng-click="addNewAddress()">Add address</button>
```

Part of my AngularJS controller:

```
var formData = {
            //...
            "addresses" : $scope.addresses
};
```

Spring Controller:

```
String[] addresses = request.getParameterValues("addresses");
for(String address : addresses) {
    System.out.println(address); //ACTUALLY PRINTS SOMETHING
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(address); //ouch error.
    System.out.println(j.toString());
}
```

The following gets printed in my spring console (I have only filled in the streetname with values 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'.

```
[{"address":"","$$hashKey":"object:4","streetname":"aaa"},{"address":"","$$hashKey":"object:6","streetname":"bbb"},{"address":"","$$hashKey":"object:8","streetname":"ccc"}]
```

The error message:

```
 A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Edit:
Now it is working thanks to the two below, I just have to point out that there is no need to use request.getParameterValues(). Instead, just use request.getParameter("valuehere") and directly parse it to a jsonarray.

Comment: I don't know spring, but are you trying to parse and array into an object ? You should parse to an array, don't you ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated my post and parsed to an array. It is still not working unfortunately

Comment: You could try `x.getJSONObject(index)` instead of a simple get.

Comment: @Moody parse first into an Array then you can work with objects

Comment: Thanks for both your comments and time. It is now working. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is from JSONObject serialization not Spring's since you are not using `@RequestBody` (you might take a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)). Your json is an array which you are trying to convert into an object `objects are the things between { }`, thats why it's given you exception, you need a JSONArray instead

```
String[] addresses = request.getParameterValues("addresses");
for(String address : addresses) {
    System.out.println(address);
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(address); //here!
    System.out.println(jArray.toString());
   //interate over array (like any other array) and do stuff, get the objects etc..
}
```

Or just change you array into an object with Angular